# Fast Pointer Increment/Decrement in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I need to inc/dec Pointers in the fastest possibile way.

I noticed that the following two function increase a Pointer by the same value, with the same final result, but the second is 4 times faster that the first.

```
procedure First(P: Pointer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1024 do
    Inc(PByte(P), 4);
end;

procedure Second(P: Pointer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1024 do 
    Inc(PCardinal(P), 1);  //Increments by 4, actually, because Cardinal is 4 bytes.
end;
```

What is the best and fastest way to Increment and Decrement Pointers in Delphi?

Comment: Are you compiling with or without optimisation? These sorts of questions can be interesting, but not if you don't bother to do the leg-work and create a [mcve]. ... ***Including timing code*** (Your question strongly suggests you're engaging in premature optimisation when you don't really have a ***real*** performance problem to solve.)

Comment: Also, please note that the implementations `First` and `Second` are conceptually different. If you try force a particular implementation for performance reasons that violates the semantics of your desired behaviour, you just make the code unnecessarily difficult to maintain.

Comment: They should equal. What makes you feel they differ in speed? Have you checked disassembly? Anyway, writing `Inc(PNativeUInt(P));` might be more accurate for what you want to do.

Comment: Question is off topic because the reported behaviour can't be reproduced.

Comment: casting takes time. do
var myPByte: PByte;
myPByte:= PByte(p);
 for i := 1 to 1024 do
    Inc(myPByte 4);

I get 5.5 faster perfomance without casting ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My test (Berlin, Win32, 10^6 repeats, stopwatch) does not show significant difference in elapsed time between these procedures.

But debug and release times differ by factor ~7 - perhaps release optimization eliminates increment of unused variable, so time is for empty loop or calls of empty function. Changing argument type to var diminishes that difference.

Generated asm code in debug mode is exactly the same for both functions (`add dword ptr [ebp-$04], $04` or `add dword ptr [eax],$04` for var-variant).

```
//parameter by value
Debug   2043 2013
Release 312  297
//var-parameter
Debug  1872 1888
Release 1732 1685
```

Anyway, speed is about milliard increments per second, so I don't believe that incrementing is real bottleneck

```
procedure First(var P: Pointer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1024 do
    Inc(PByte(P), 4);
end;

procedure Second(var P: Pointer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1024 do
    Inc(PCardinal(P), 1);  //Increments by 4, actually, because Cardinal is 4 bytes.
end;

var
  Sw: TStopWatch;
  k: Integer;
  t, t2: int64;
  p: Pointer;
begin
  sw.Start;

  t := sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  for k := 1 to 1000000 do begin
      p := nil;
      First(p);
  end;
  t2 := sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  Memo1.Lines.Add (IntToStr(t2 - t));

  t := sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  for k := 1 to 1000000 do begin
      p := nil;
      Second(p);
  end;
  t2 := sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  Memo1.Lines.Add (IntToStr(t2 - t));
  sw.Stop;
```